# apache flink windows installation

Tags: apache-flink

I am trying to install flink on windows running into all sorts of problems . Please help.

1. Downloading the tar file from net, does not give me windows bat file options. Used the download links at https://flink.apache.org/downloads.html#apache-flink-1111. So i cannot run start-local.bat. Infact i dont even have start-local.sh . I ended up installing cygwin just so i can run start cluster bat
2. However running the start cluster bat is giving weird issues and exiting immediately.
   $ ./start-cluster.sh
   Starting cluster.
   Starting standalonesession daemon on host DESKTOP**.
   Starting taskexecutor daemon on host DESKTOP**.

Error: Could not create the Java Virtual Machine.
Error: A fatal exception has occurred. Program will exit.
Improperly specified VM option 'MaxMetaspaceSize=268435456
'

Answer (score 0):

This is an open bug for sometime and is deferred to Flink 1.14 version.

https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/FLINK-18438

https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/FLINK-18792